# Cannot open files with QFileDialog (Qt 5.7)

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

I'm creating an audio player with Qt 5.7 on Windows 10.
The program works but when I load an audio file it return these errors

```
shell\comdlg32\fileopensave.cpp(14274)\comdlg32.dll!75622833: (caller: 7565211C) ReturnHr(1) tid(dec) 80004005 Not specified error.
    CallContext:[\PickerModalLoop] 

shell\osshell\lmui\ntshrui\dll\shrengine.cpp(1473)\ntshrui.dll!665E3BE2: (caller: 665DF284) ReturnHr(1) tid(1a14) 80004005 Not specified error.
```

This is the function

```
void AudioPlayer::loadClicked()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Select an audio file"), "" ,tr("File Mp3 (*.mp3)"));
    int volume = ui->horizontalSliderVolume->value();

    if(!filename.isEmpty())
    {
        player.setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(filename));
        player.setVolume(volume);
    }
}
```

Why? How can I resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to this [Qt bug ticket](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52618). It is actually only warnings produced by Windows, but your application should be fine. The messages themselves apparently cannot be removed.

Comment: @Andrien Levarat Thanks